# Alert not getting triggered JS

Tags: javascript, html

i have made a program of a mock Shopping cart and ive recently tried to implement something that should prevent adding more than one instance of the same item inside the cart but the alert i have set up doesn't seem to trigger when i add the same item again into the cart.

Relevant Html

```
<div class="store-item">
                <span class="product-name">Cpu-1</span>
                <img class="cpu-image" src="Images/Cpu-1.jpg">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <span class="item-price">$229.99</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary item-button" role="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="store-item">
                <span class="product-name">Cpu-2</span>
                <img class="cpu-image" src="Images/Cpu-2.jpg">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <span class="item-price">$129.99</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary item-button" role="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="container text-content">
        <h2 class="section-head">CART</h2>
        <div class="cart-row">
            <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">PRODUCT</span>
            <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">COST</span>
            <span class="cart-quantity cart-head cart-column">AMOUNT</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-items">
            <div class="cart-row">
                <div class="cart-item cart-column">
                <img class="checkout-cpu" src="Images/R9-7950.jpg" width="100" height="100">
                <span class="checkout-item">Ryzen 9-7950X</span>
            </div>
            <span class="cart-column cart-price">$799.99</span>
            <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                <form>
                <input class="checkout-input" type="number" value="1" autocomplete="off">
                </form>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" role="button">REMOVE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section>
        <div class="cart-total">
            <strong class="cart-sum">SUM</strong>
            <span class="cart-sum-amount">$799.99</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-checkout" role="button">Check Out</button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Relevant JavaScript

```
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }
}
```

```
function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem  = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var cpuName = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product-name')[0].innerHTML
    var cpuPrice = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerHTML
    var cpuImg = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('cpu-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(cpuName, cpuPrice, cpuImg)
}

function addItemToCart(cpuName, cpuPrice, cpuImg) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('product-name')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innertext == cpuName) {
            alert('item already in cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="checkout-cpu" src="${cpuImg}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="checkout-item">${cpuName}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-column cart-price">${cpuPrice}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <form>
            <input class="checkout-input" type="number" value="1" autocomplete="off">
            </form>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" role="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
        cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
}
```

Comment: `innertext` doesn’t exist. You mean [`innerText`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), but note that [`textContent`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is preferred.

Comment: used innerHTML innerText textContent, but still nothing

Comment: Using random properties won't help you. Debug your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('item-button')
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButtons[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target
  var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
  var cpuName = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product-name')[0].innerHTML
  var cpuPrice = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerHTML
  var cpuImg = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('cpu-image')[0].src
  addItemToCart(cpuName, cpuPrice, cpuImg)
}

function addItemToCart(cpuName, cpuPrice, cpuImg) {
  var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
  cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
  var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('checkout-item')
  for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
    if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == cpuName) {
      alert('item already in cart')
      return
    }
  }

  var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="checkout-cpu" src="${cpuImg}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="checkout-item">${cpuName}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-column cart-price">${cpuPrice}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <form>
            <input class="checkout-input" type="number" value="1" autocomplete="off">
            </form>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" role="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
  cartItems.append(cartRow)
}
```

```html
<div class="store-item">
  <span class="product-name">Cpu-1</span>
  <img class="cpu-image" src="Images/Cpu-1.jpg">
  <div class="product-details">
    <span class="item-price">$229.99</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary item-button" role="button">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="store-item">
  <span class="product-name">Cpu-2</span>
  <img class="cpu-image" src="Images/Cpu-2.jpg">
  <div class="product-details">
    <span class="item-price">$129.99</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary item-button" role="button">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="container text-content">
  <h2 class="section-head">CART</h2>
  <div class="cart-row">
    <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">PRODUCT</span>
    <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">COST</span>
    <span class="cart-quantity cart-head cart-column">AMOUNT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-items">
    <div class="cart-row">
      <div class="cart-item cart-column">
        <img class="checkout-cpu" src="Images/R9-7950.jpg" width="100" height="100">
        <span class="checkout-item">Ryzen 9-7950X</span>
      </div>
      <span class="cart-column cart-price">$799.99</span>
      <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
        <form>
          <input class="checkout-input" type="number" value="1" autocomplete="off">
        </form>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" role="button">REMOVE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="cart-total">
    <strong class="cart-sum">SUM</strong>
    <span class="cart-sum-amount">$799.99</span>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-checkout" role="button">Check Out</button>
</section>
```

As mentioned in the comments there is no such property as innertext. You have a typo.
And another problem was wrong class name
var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('**checkout-item**')